# Convert WHERE condition into LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables student and encounter. I want to convert this WHERE to LEFT JOIN. Is this possible?

```
WHERE stu.student_id NOT IN (
SELECT student_id
FROM encounter
WHERE 
AND deletion_date IS NULL
AND '2013-12-04'::date BETWEEN start_date AND Coalesce(end_date, '2013-12-04'::date)
)
```

Comment: Please post your full query to get proper help

Comment: Yes it's possible, but the rest of the query would help so that a complete answer can be given.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  student stu
  LEFT JOIN encounter enc ON enc.student_id = stu.student_id
    AND enc.deletion_date IS NULL
    AND '2013-12-04'::date BETWEEN start_date AND COALESCE(end_date, '2013-12-04'::date)
WHERE
  enc.student_id IS NULL
```

---

Personally I would use a NOT EXISTS sub-query,

```
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM   encounter 
    WHERE  student_id = stu.student_id
           AND deletion_date IS NULL
           AND '2013-12-04'::date > start_date
           AND (end_date IS NULL OR '2013-12-04'::date < end_date)
  )
```

along with an index on encounter over `(student_id, start_date, end_date, deletion_date)`.

That way the sub-query would amount to one *index seek* operation per `student` record, which should go reasonably fast. If it is faster than the alternatives you must benchmark yourself.

Answer (score 0):

may this help you:

```
SELECT <columns you want to view> FROM student s
LEFT JOIN encounter e ON s.student_id != e.student_id
WHERE <provide your filtration here>
```